# Chrome addon - update URL?

Tags: google-chrome, add-on

Here is my manifest JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Name of addon",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Description",
  "icons": {
    "48" : "icon-48.png",
    "128" : "icon-128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.youtube.com/watch?*","http://youtube.com/watch?*","https://*.youtube.com/watch?*","https://youtube.com/watch?*"],
      "js" : ["script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I host this addon on my server, not at the Chrome app store or on any other external place.

I am looking to integrate version tracking in to the addon some how, so as soon as I release a new version, I can edit a file somewhere and Chrome will know to alert the user to download the new version?

Is this possible?

For example - this is version 1.0.0

Say I create version 1.1.0 and upload it to my server.

I then edit a file for example: http://www.mysite.com/file and change the version number to 1.1.0 - when the user loads Chrome again, the addon will check that link to see if a new version is available and then donwload the update from X url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/autoupdate.html